# Phonegap - read android preferences.xml values, JQM List

Tags: android, xml, jquery-mobile, cordova, preferences

this is what im after now...
In my phonegap app, i have a JQM list. One list item is this:

```
<li class="none" data-icon="arrow-r">
<a href="epl.html" rel="external" ><img src="img/epl-48x48.png"  />
  <h3>EPL</h3>
</a>
</li>
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/VapIA.png

In my native java section of my app, i have Preferences class (extends PreferenceActivity) screen, which is a CheckBoxPreference (xml layout) thats toggles on/off which i want to enable or disable the list item above.
To disable (hide) the JQM list item above i just change the HTML class from class="none" .. to class="ui-screen-hidden" .. which obviously hides the list item. Great.
But my question now is how to i connect the preferences in my saved native Preferences, so i can apply changes to the phonegap HTML class (i.e. set the class="ui-screen-hidden" in JQM list), based on the toggle value of my native preferences class.
I hope i am making sense. See screen shots attached.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/rP6pt.png

Thanks,
Darren.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

U can write a phoegap android plugin to pass the value between your activity to javascript and then apply the changes u want. 
http://wiki.phonegap.com/w/page/36753494/How%20to%20Create%20a%20PhoneGap%20Plugin%20for%20Android

Comment: Yes this seems to be the only way to do it. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I can now say that an Android [AppPreferences](https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugins/tree/master/Android/AppPreferences) plugin is now available. I know dmac knows this as he helped test it. Small [write up](http://simonmacdonald.blogspot.com/2012/06/phongap-android-application-preferences.html) on it on my blog.